# Remover Row seleccionado de DGV

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy tratando de eliminar el row seleccionado de un dgv y mi base de datos, usando SP.

El problema es que no me elimina el row seleccionado, me elimina 3 registros pero no el seleccionado, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DGVListData.Rows)

        {

        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete_ExtDataSelected", cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdApp", cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdModule", cmbSelectMod.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idRow", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(); 
            DGVListData.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Cells[0].RowIndex);
           int  numRes = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (numRes > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted Succefull!", "Great", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                loadDGVData();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Try Again !!!", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            cnx.Close();
        }

        }
    }
```

Este es mi SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_ExtDataSelected]
```

(
@idApp int,
@idModule int,
@idRow int
)
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [dbo].[ExternalData]
WHERE (idApplication = @idApp AND idModule = @idModule AND id = @idRow)

idApp y idModule, son las claves foraneas en mi tabla estos valores los toma de un comboBox y idRow es el id de mi tabla ExternalData.

Alguna idea de que puede estar mal?

Saludos

DS

Comment: Que sentencia ejecuta "Delete_ExtDataSelected"? Podrias editar la pregunta y poner la query SQL a la que apunta esa instrucción?
la función `loadDGVData()` tampoco la veo en el codigo, puedes ponerla tambien?

Comment: El tema principal es que aqui haces un foreach por cada row de la grid, y la pasas por una sentencia de DELETE, pasandole por parametro 3 valores de los cuales solamente 1 puede ser variable por cada iteración del foreach

Comment: He editado la pregunta agregando el SP SQL. @Marc

Comment: El control DataGridView dispone de la propiedad SelectedRows. Basta con hacer el for each sobre la colección SelectedRows. Cada fila que puedas recorrer en dicha colección es que está seleccionada y si pretendes borrar las seleccionadas pues ahí las tienes. En tu código no entiendo dónde discriminas las que están seleccionadas de las que no ya que recorres la totalidad de filas del Grid y no veo que preguntes si está seleccionada o no para aplicar el borrado.